# Php call static method of class which is in variable

Tags: php, variables, namespaces

I have a namespace `App\Term` which is saved as a property: `$this->name = 'App\Term'`. How can I call a static method of this class like `$this->name::methodName()` ? Or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Does `$name::methodName()` not work?

Comment: I updated the question. It should be not a simple variable like `$name`. It is a property: `$this->name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func` for this.

```
call_user_func($name.'::methodName');
```

Or:

```
call_user_func(array($name, 'methodName'));
```

Comment: Perfect. I works even with property: `call_user_func($this->name.'::methodName');`